# Please help me with java ee and eclipse tutorial

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee

im new to java ee platform and im having a hard time searching for a book for java ee that uses eclipse IDE. So please can you tell me any book that involves java ee and eclipse for beginners. and some tips from you how to learn this stuff and a follow up question, is java EE still good 20 years from now?

Comment: the answer is a simple google search away, however it looks like a throwaway account from you.

Answer (score 1):

How about [Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/moreinfo/jee.php) with links to [tutorials](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?r=1&file=/technology/phoenix/europa/EclipseIdeForJeeDevelopers), [books](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321396855), and [on-line documents](http://www.eclipse.org/documentation/) aplenty?

Will people be maintaining legacy J2EE code 20 years from now? Sure, people are maintaining legacy code today that was written 40 years ago. Will people be writing new J2EE code 20 years from now? Almost certainly not.